# Nominatim search.php is not working while reverse.php is working fine

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I face some troubles regarding the installation of `nominatim`. The `search.php` results with
`##Nominatimserver## is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`.

I have installed `Nominatim 3.1.0` on `Ubuntu 18.04` with `postgres 10` and run `./utils/setup.php --index --create-search-indices` twice to be sure that the indices were created successfully.

However the output of the `setup.php...` is `Starting rank 0 Done 0 in 0 @ 0.000000 per second - FINISHED` for each rank.

My guess is that the indices are not build correct as the reverse search is working fine.

Any ideas what I can do/check?

Comment: Duplicate: https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/issues/1162

Comment: From linked Github issue: "It was a problem of using postgres 10 with Nominatim 3.1.0 instead of Nominatim 3.2.0"